# Python celery database result storage specify table name

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

I am currently attempting to migrate a Django web application from python 2.7 to 3.8, but during the migration we would like to run a blue/green setup with both environments operating somewhat separately from each other.

We use celery for task execution and in Python 2.7 we were storing the results of tasks in a database table named 'celery_taskmeta', currently our Python 3.8 environment is also trying to use this table name but failing due to differences in table DDL.

We noticed in celery documentation that it is possible to control this based on: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.4.6/userguide/configuration.html#database-table-names

but cannot seem to make this work based on the example given in the documentation. For example we've tried specifying;

`results_backend = settings.CELERY_RESULT_DB_TABLE_NAMES`

and also in django settings;

`CELERY_RESULT_DB_TABLE_NAMES = { 'task': 'python38_taskmeta', 'group': 'python38_groupmeta', }`

But we still see Celery using the table name of 'celery_taskmeta' and it seems like the documentation is a little vague when it comes to this parameter, would anyone happen to know how this setting can be provided to the app?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
database_table_names = {
    'task': 'myapp_taskmeta',
    'group': 'myapp_groupmeta',
}
```

Reference: [Link](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.4.6/userguide/configuration.html#database-table-names)